# While automating UI tests for angular SPA (Single Page Application) using Coded UI, clicking icons on home page does not work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, coded-ui-tests

I am working to automate UI/acceptance tests for an angular SPA (Single Page Application) using Coded UI.

The client side is completely developed on Angular and Bootstrap. We also use kendo controls like kendo grid. We use the ‘UI-Router’ framework built in Angular for routing.

To automate a sample test case - “Open DataTable app from Home page” using Coded UI, following are the steps:
1)      Open IE and go to WebConsole home page 
2)      Identify DataTable icon.
3)      Click on the icon.
4)      Validate DataTable app.

I am able to automate steps 1-3, but after clicking on the DataTable icon, the DataTable app is not being displayed. The UI still shows the Home page.

We tried clicking the DataTable icon manually during the test run to see whether the click is working and it did not work.

I tried searching on web about this but could not find anything useful.

Any pointer in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Potential options I use for finicky controls

```
using mshtml;
var htmlHtmlElement = yourControl.NativeElement as HTMLHtmlElement;
if (htmlHtmlElement != null)
{
     htmlHtmlElement.click();
}
```

Or

```
control.RunScript("arguments[0].click();");
// Extension class
private static object RunScript(this HtmlControl control, string script)
{
    var bw = control.TopParent as BrowserWindow;
    return bw.ExecuteScript(script, control);
}
```